# Converting a complex html.erb anchor to haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following code in a partial that I am trying to convert to HAML.  Everything is easy until the anchor.

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class="stats">
  <table summary="User stats">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
          <span id="following" class="stat">
            <%= @user.following.count %> following
          </span>
        </a>
```

I got it close with:

```
- @user ||= current_user
.stats
  %table{ :summary => "User stats" }
    %tr
      %td
        %a
          = following_user_path(@user)
          %span.stat#following
            = @user.following.count
            following
```

but the anchor does not quite come out right.
I believe that I should be able to do this with a link_to but I am unclear on how to mix the embedded SPAN tag within the arguments for link_to.  How should this be done?
Thank you for any help.
Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `link_to` helper:

```
= link_to following_user_path(@user) do
  %span#following.stat
    == #{@user.following.count} following
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use:

```
    %a{ :href => following_user_path(@user) }
      %span.stat#following
        = @user.following.count
        following
```

Comment: Very good, thank you.  I am also looking to understand if there is a way to do it with link_to. Does the complexity of the items keep one from doing it with link_to?

Comment: Yes, you can.
link_to method can receive optional hash parameter and there you can set class, id and other attributes of anchor element.
Something like:
link_to 'Link', '#', :id => 'element_id', :class => 'element_class'